# Quick way to prove that for sufficiently large $n$, $[kn,(k+1)n]$ contains a prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I would like to prove that, for any integer $k$, for all sufficiently large $n$ we have $[kn,(k+1)n]$ contains a prime.

I want a proof that is

1. As elementary as possible. (that is, use the results of prime distributions as small as possible)
2. As quick as possible.

Additionally, if this proof can proof that there are $\frac{n}{C\log k \log n}$ primes (for some constant $C$ that does not depend on $k,n$), or relaxed to there are $\frac{n}{C_k \log n}$ primes ($C_k$ is a constant that depends on $k$), I will be really appreciated. I tried to repeat the proof for $k=1$ which is presented below, but the combinatoric number $\binom{(k+1)n}n$ is too small comparing to $4^{kn}$, that is, the upper bound of the product of all primes smaller than $kn$...

Here I attach the sketch of the proof for $k=1$ (Checyshev's Theorem). Let $m$ be the number of primes in $[n,2n]$. Consider $\binom{2n}{n}$. We know that $\binom{2n}n=2^{2n-o(n)}$. Also, we factorize it to

$$\binom {2n}n=\prod_{p<\sqrt{2n}}p^{\nu_p}\prod_{\sqrt{2n}<p<2/3n}p^{\nu_p}\prod_{p>n}p^{\nu_p}$$
Where $\nu_p$ is the exponential of $p$ in $\binom{2n}n$. For prime $p$ we have $\nu_p$ equals to the number of carries in the addition $n+n=2n$, thus it is no larger than $\log_{p}2n$. Specifically, we have $\nu_p=1$ for $p>\sqrt{2n}$. So we have

$$\binom {2n}n=\prod_{p<\sqrt{2n}}p^{\nu_p}\prod_{\sqrt{2n}<p<2/3n}p^{\nu_p}\prod_{p>n}p^{\nu_p}\le\prod_{p<\sqrt{2n}}(2n)\prod_{\sqrt{2n}<p<2/3n}p\prod_{p>n}p\le (2n)^{\sqrt{2n}}4^{2/3n}\prod_{p>n}p^{\nu_p}\le2^{4/3n+o(n)}(2n)^m$$
Here we used the fact that the product of primes smaller than $r$ is at most $4^r$. Therefore, from above, we have

$$2^{2n-o(n)}\le 2^{4/3n+o(n)}(2n)^m$$
And thus we have $(2n)^{m}\ge 2^{2/3n+o(n)}$, which means that $m\ge\frac{2/3n+o(n)}{\log 2n}=\Omega(\frac{n}{\log n})$

Comment: A solution with the prime number thorem is of an interest to you?

Comment: @UdiFogiel Thank you for your comment, if you mean by using the fact that $\pi(n)\sim \frac{n}{\log n}$, I won't ask here... I am here looking for a solution that does not rely on many (especially, strong) prime distribution theorems, that is what I mean "as elementary as possible"...

Comment: I think the bigger $k$ is, the harder it gets to construct a proof without falling back on the Prime Number Theorem.

Comment: See J. Nagura. On the interval containing at least one prime number. Proc. Japan
Acad., 28:177–181, 1952 for the case $k=5$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you but I wonder can I construct a proof similar to the case when $k=1$ in the problem description using combinatorical numbers...?

Comment: Have you looked at the Nagura paper, Jet?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes I had a glance at it but... that is not exactly the proof I need... although that proof we can extend it to all $k$ case using a better estimation repeatedly using Lemma 1 to get a better bound for $\psi$ and $\vartheta$ but that is really not the thing I need...

Comment: There is some discussion at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289402/who-first-proved-the-generalization-of-bertrands-postulate-to-2n-3n-and-3n-4 that may be relevant. Also discussed at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127248/at-what-point-would-an-elementary-generalization-of-bertrands-postulate-be-inte

Comment: There is a preprint, Shiva Kintali, A generalization of Erdös' proof of Bertrand-Chebyshev Theorem, available at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228592091_A_Generalization_of_Erdos's_Proof_of_Bertrand-Chebyshev_Theorem but I don't know whether it has ever been evaluated by a referee. So far as I know, it has never been published, so you'll want to read it carefully to see whether it hangs together. For what it's worth, the author's degrees are all in Computer Science.

Comment: In the bounty notice, you ask for "a proof that is similar to the Chebyshev's theorem," but proofs and theorems are two different classes of objects, and it makes no sense to speak of one being similar to the other. I *think* what you want is a proof similar to *Erdös' proof of* Chebyshev's Theorem. Did you see anything of interest at the MathOverflow links I gave?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for pointing out, but I can't fix the notice (since in the notice I have explicitly stated "as in the problem statement") The preprint by Shiva Kintali seems to be what I want there. I will give a reward if you could form it as an answer here.

Comment: I hesitate to cite Kintali's preprint as an answer, for the reasons I've given.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Okay... I will post an answer myself if I find his paper is correct and write in my language.